# iOS 8 - username UITextField secures entry when becoming first responder AFTER the password text field

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I encountered an issue with a classic configuration: username/password textfields.
Nothing special, just 2 UITextFields, one with "Secure Text Entry" checked, that's it.

When I tap on the username textfield, it is normal. 
Then I tap on the password textfield, the text is secured (big dots). 
And when I tap again on the username textfield, the text of both textfields is secured!

If I tap outside of the password textfield before tapping again on the username password, the text is still secured.
However, if after that, I tap outside of the username textfield and then on the username textfield again, the text is not secured.
Also, if I change the text of the username textfield while it is secured, it becomes normal again.

Bug occurs on iOS8 (not iOS7).

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the secure text entry in code anywhere?

Comment: Nope, just using the checkbox in the xib file

Comment: I have the same frustrating error. I start to think, that it could be an iOS8 bug

Comment: Share your code. Without seeing your code we cannot figure out the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague added that and it worked

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.usernameText)
    {
        self.usernameText.secureTextEntry = YES;
        self.usernameText.secureTextEntry = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This only happens when you have the SAME text in your username and password textfield. This is a iOS8-Bug, but as this is very very likely never going to happen in "real-world" scenarios it isn't that bad (Still pretty buggy though).
As soon as the username doesn't match the password anymore, it works as it did in iOS7.

I hope this helps you out a bit

Answer (score 0):

> usernameTextField.tag = 0; 
>   passwordTextField.tag = 1;

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch(textField.tag) {
        case 0:
        textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
        break;
        case 1:
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This also might help.